# Finding the index of (x,y) pairs in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, compile

I have a large list of $(x,y)$ pairs, and I want to find the index of a particular pair in order to extract some data from another array.

By way of an example,

```
samplelist = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}], 1];
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 
  4}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 
  2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}} *)

position = Last@Last@Position[(Boole[# == {1, 3}] & /@ samplelist), n_ /; n == 1];
(* 3 *)

samplelist[[position]]
(* {1, 3} *)
```

Which is great. But I want to compile this, as the rest of my code is also compiled.

Just doing the following, with `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True]`, returns an error because `n_ /; n == 1` cannot be compiled.

Note that without the above system options set, it returns no error message, but clearly hasn't compiled, as doing a `CompilePrint` on the function shows it hasn't.

```
myPos = Compile[{{list, _Real, 2}, {val, _Real, 1}},
   Position[(Boole[# == val] & /@ list), n_ /; n == 1]];
```

Is there a way to overcome this and create a compiled function that does what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
f = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 2}, {val, _Real, 1}}, First@First@Position[lst, val]];
f[samplelist, {1, 3}]
(*3*)
```

Comment: Well there we go, knew I was missing something, thanks!